# AlarmManager и добавление множества Alarm

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver, android-alarm-manager, android-broadcastreceiver

Имеется таблица в БД, в которой каждая запись содержит день недели, часы и минуты для сигнала (что-то вроде будильника). И, когда наступает время, должна вызываться активити (при чём, даже в режиме сна, но это детали уже).
Вот, накидал такой код:

```
public class TaskScanner {

    Context context;
    DBHelper dbHelper;

    public TaskScanner (Context context, DBHelper dbHelper) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbHelper = dbHelper;
    }

    /**
     * Сканирование задач из таблицы SCHEDULE
     * и установка их сигналов
     */
    public void scanTasks () {
        int rows = dbHelper.getRowsQuantity("SCHEDULE");

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query("SCHEDULE", null, null, null, null, null, null);

        int dayColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("DAY");
        int hourColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("HOURS");
        int minuteColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("MINUTES");

        // Цикл для чтения таблицы БД и записи данных в переменные
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++) {
            // Дефолтные значения переменных
            int hour = 0;
            int minute = 0;
            int dayOfWeek = 0;

            // Получение значений из БД
            if (c.moveToNext()) {
                hour = c.getInt(hourColIndex);
                minute = c.getInt(minuteColIndex);
                dayOfWeek = c.getInt(dayColIndex);
            }

            // Получение объекта календаря с текущим временем
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            // добавление сигнала
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek + 1);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("alarm message", "alarm message");
            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 192837, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
            }
    }
}
```

И **BroadcastReceiver** :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String ACTION_BOOT = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (ACTION_BOOT.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            try {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");
                Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, SignalsActivity.class);
                newIntent.putExtra("alarm_message", message);
                newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(newIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вызываю метод *scanTasks()* в MainActivity в onCreate();

Не работает. (Что, наверное, и не странно).
Большое спасибо за Ваши ответы!

Comment: Скорее всего вы невнимательно прочитали любой пример из интернета и забыли добавить объявление ресивера в манифест.

Comment: Такое? 
`<receiver android:name='.AlarmManagerEx.AlarmReceiver'>
        </receiver>` 
(Внутри тега `<application>`)

Comment: Вроде оно, да...

Comment: И кстати, вы в вашем ресивере реагируете только на событие окончательной загрузки девайса. Вы точно этого хотите?...

Comment: Нет, это недописано просто. Но проблема в том, что после перезапуска устройства код по прежнему не работает. Активити не вызывается. И я думаю, что это связано с тем, что вызов метода для добавления сигналов происходит в Activity. С этим моментом я не разобрался. Возможно необходимо вызывать этот метод где-то в ресивере, ибо в манифесте прописан именно он, и как я понимаю, после перезапуска работает только ресивер (из всего приложения). Верно?

Comment: Под "активити не вызывается" имеете в виду, что она не вызывается или что не вызывается ресивер, её вызывающий? И да, установка алармов может быть сделана при приёме сообщения о полной загрузке. Проверьте ещё, что у вас разрешение на подписку на событие загрузки также в манифесте есть. и что ресиверу указано через фильтр на него реагировать.

Comment: В манифесте:
`    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`
На счёт активити, то да, имел ввиду, что не запускается ресивер, который её запускает (во здесь: `Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, SignalsActivity.class); context.startActivity(newIntent);`).

Comment: Ну... Добавьте целиком объявление ресивера из манифеста.