# AlarmReceiver, WakefulBroadcastReceiver и установка будильников

Tags: android, android-sdk, broadcast-receiver, android-alarm-manager, android-broadcastreceiver

Здравствуйте! Подобный вопрос уже был от меня, но ответа, который решил бы мою проблему на него не получил. Наверное, не стоит писать здесь свой код, так как скорее всего, я выбрал неверный подход к решению задачи. Тем не менее, оставлю ссылку на свой предыдущий вопрос: [тут мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510493/alarmmanager-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-alarm).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать следующую задачу:
Есть таблица в БД, в которой находятся записи.
Колонки в таблице:
[ID][NAME][DAY][HOURS][MINUTES]

Также есть Активити, которую нужно вызывать в заданное время.

То есть, нужно сканировать таблицу в БД, и на основе этих данных нужно установить Alarm-ы, которые будут вызывать Активити.

Содержимое Активити менять не нужно (оно будет менятся уже в onCreate()  самой Активити).

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как поставить alarm-ы в множественном числе. Опять-таки, по ссылке, приведённой выше, я показал своё виденье реализации задачи.

Заранее спасибо за ответы, очень надеюсь на Вашу помощь, ибо без решения этой задачи не могу двигаться дальше :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте в Вашем коде заменить на это:

```
 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("alarm message", "alarm message");
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
    } else {
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
    }
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Просто для разных версий андроида регистрация `pendingIntent`-a  происходит по-разному. Плюс, вы всегда регистрировали его под номером 192837, я заменил его на `i`, так как эта переменная используется в цикле, и она будет уникальная, и каждый последующий `pendingIntent`  не будет перезаписывать предыдущий.

Если есть необходимость удалить все зарегестрированные интенты, то вызовите такую функцию:

```
public static void clearAlarmReceiver(Context context, int intentsCount) {
        for (int i = 0; i < intentsCount; i++) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CheckAlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            pendingIntent.cancel();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш код заработал. Но теперь появилась другая проблема: будильники срабатывают мгновенно. Видимо, из-за того, что некоторые из них установлены на уже прошедшее время. Как это фильтровать?

Comment: Перед установкой алярмов, удаляйте все предыдущие кодом, который я привел выше. Ну или как вариант в самом broadcastReceiver-e сравнивать по дате. Но для этого в intent.putExtra кладите дату алярма.